# Repository and Unit Of Work pattern in non MVC projects

Tags: asp.net, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Can we use Repository and Unit Of Work pattern in non ASP.Net MVC projects? If so, please let me know how to implement this (project layers/structure) in a normal ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can and the structure is identical.  I would have a data repository project, a models project and a business logic project.  my web app would then talk to the model and business layers.

i throw in AutoMapper in this type of app to translate between the model and data models.

i would then return the model back to the asp page and i would implement **MVP** there too.

this is a very high level look at your issue without knowing anything about your project or environment.

you might need to give us more to go on OP if you want a more in depth answer

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a25b0ea8-4bf8-4d29-945a-d65daf89c9ea/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14642/Model-View-Presenter-with-ASP-NET